# Check database for access in Spring Gateway Pre filter

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-reactive, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using Spring Gateway, where I need to check further user access by Request path using DB call. My repository is like this.

```
public Mono<ActionMapping> getByUri(String url)
....
```

This is my current filter where I am using custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` implementation.

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

    return (exchange, chain) -> exchange
        .getPrincipal()
        .filter(principal -> principal instanceof UserAuthenticationToken) // Custom implementation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
        .cast(UserAuthenticationToken.class)
        .map(userAuthenticationToken -> extractAuthoritiesAndSetThatToRequest(exchange, userAuthenticationToken))
        .defaultIfEmpty(exchange)
        .flatMap(chain::filter);
}

private ServerWebExchange extractAuthoritiesAndSetThatToRequest(ServerWebExchange exchange, UserAuthenticationToken authentication) {

    var uriActionMapping = uriActionMappingRepository.findOneByUri(exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString()).block();

    if ((uriActionMapping == null) || (authentication.getPermission().containsKey(uriActionMapping.getName()))) {

        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest()
                                            .mutate()
                                            .header("X-Auth", authentication.getName())
                                            .build();

        return exchange.mutate().request(request).build();
    }

    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.setComplete();

    return exchange.mutate().response(response).build();
}
```

However, there are several problems here, first that it is blocking call. Also I am not sure I need to mutate `exchange` to return response like that. Is there anyway achieve this using filter in Spring Cloud Gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a blocking call.

Firstly, Spring WebFlux is based on Reactor. In Reactor, most handling method will not recieve a `null` from `Mono` emit, e.g. `map`, `flatMap`. Sure, there are counterexamples, such as `doOnSuccess`, see also the [javadoc of `Mono`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html).

So, we can just use handling methods to filter results instead of `block`. Those handling methods will return a empty `Mono` when recieve a `null` value.

Secondary, when it authorize failed, we should return a empty Mono instead of calling `chain.filter`. The `chain.filter` means "It's OK! Just do something after the Filter!". See also `RequestRateLimiterGatewayFilterFactory`, it also mutate the `response`.

So, we should set `response` to completed, and return a empty `Mono` if authorize failed.

Try this:

```java
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> exchange
        .getPrincipal()
        .filter(principal -> principal instanceof UserAuthenticationToken) // Custom implementation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
        .cast(UserAuthenticationToken.class)
        .flatMap(userAuthenticationToken -> extractAuthoritiesAndSetThatToRequest(exchange, userAuthenticationToken))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> exchange.getResponse().setComplete().then(Mono.empty())))
        .flatMap(chain::filter);
}

// Maybe return empty Mono, e.g. findOneByUri not found, or Permissions does not containing
private Mono<ServerWebExchange> extractAuthoritiesAndSetThatToRequest(ServerWebExchange exchange, UserAuthenticationToken authentication) {
    return uriActionMappingRepository.findOneByUri(exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString())
        .filter(it -> authentication.getPermission().containsKey(it.getName()))
        .map(it -> exchange.mutate()
            .request(builder -> builder.header("X-Auth", authentication.getName()))
            .build());
}
```

About mutate `request`, see also `RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory`.

Comment: I had to make some changes but your solution worked thank you.